# Scraping data from current as well as nested links at the same time using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am fairly new to scraping pages using Scrapy.
While trying to scrape quotes along with details of each author from the respective links for them I encountered a problem.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesProject(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quote'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {}
        for x in response.css('.quote'):
            item['quote'] = x.css('.text::text').get()
            item['author'] = x.css('.author::text').get()
            item['href'] = response.urljoin(x.css('a::attr(href)').get())

            yield scrapy.Request(item['href'], callback=self.parse_inside, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_inside(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['aauthor'] = response.css('h3::text').get()
        return item
```

The desired output for each quote is as follows, where `author` and `aauthor` should have the same value(but `aauthor` is fetched from another page):

```
{'quote': '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”', 'author': 'Steve Martin', 'href': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'aauthor': 'Steve Martin'}
```

However I'm getting quite unexpected output

```
2019-04-04 15:45:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-04-04 15:45:52 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-04-04 15:45:52 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-04-04 15:45:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-04-04 15:45:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/> (referer: None)
2019-04-04 15:45:53 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2019-04-04 15:45:53 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Andre-Gide/> from <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Andre-Gide>
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Andre-Gide/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/)
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/> from <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein>
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe/> from <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe>
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling/> from <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling>
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt/> from <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt>
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin/> from <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin>
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen/> from <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen>
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Thomas-A-Edison/> from <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Thomas-A-Edison>
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Andre-Gide/>
{'quote': '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”', 'author': 'Steve Martin', 'href': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'aauthor': 'André Gide\n    '}
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/)
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/)
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/)
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/)
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/)
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/)
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Thomas-A-Edison/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/)
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling/>
{'quote': '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”', 'author': 'Steve Martin', 'href': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'aauthor': 'J.K. Rowling\n    '}
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen/>
{'quote': '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”', 'author': 'Steve Martin', 'href': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'aauthor': 'Eleanor Roosevelt\n    '}
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt/>
{'quote': '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”', 'author': 'Steve Martin', 'href': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'aauthor': 'Marilyn Monroe\n    '}
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/>
{'quote': '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”', 'author': 'Steve Martin', 'href': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'aauthor': 'Steve Martin\n    '}
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe/>
{'quote': '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”', 'author': 'Steve Martin', 'href': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'aauthor': 'Steve Martin\n    '}
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin/>
{'quote': '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”', 'author': 'Steve Martin', 'href': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'aauthor': 'Steve Martin\n    '}
2019-04-04 15:45:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Thomas-A-Edison/>
{'quote': '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”', 'author': 'Steve Martin', 'href': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'aauthor': 'Thomas A. Edison\n    '}
```

It seems to complete all iterations of the `parse()` method and use the last `item` dictionary for later links. But if that's the case, all the `aauthor` values should have been the same. I searched a lot for the solution, but everything was beyond what I could understand at this point.Also, the requests seem to be asynchronous.

Would appreciate if someone explains the problem along with a working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good, just move `item` creation to cycle, otherwise this is the same object with the same data:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for x in response.css('.quote'):
        item = {}
        item['quote'] = x.css('.text::text').get()
        item['author'] = x.css('.author::text').get()
        item['href'] = response.urljoin(x.css('a::attr(href)').get())
        yield scrapy.Request(item['href'], callback=self.parse_inside, meta={'item': item})
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked!! I know that it's a basic Python question, but should not the values get overridden each time the loop runs and fetches a new value?

Comment: As far as I understand, you have a "link" to one object, so since going through loop is faster than async calling new requests, you have just last version of data in this object. Correct me, if I am wrong.